# Users Unable to Access Dashboard/Posts/Pages

Tags: wp-admin, users, user-roles

I'm trying to set user roles in order for my users to access the wp-admin Dashboard section and post. I was able to create roles and give multiple users Shop Manager/ Editor roles. But when they login to the website they are able to see the top part of the Admin Area. But when they click on a link like Dashboard or Posts it just ends up returning them to the Home Page of the website. I used the plugin Edit User Role Editor in order to give the correct permissions. But for some reason it does not allow them To Add Post/Edit Post/ etc.. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. If you fix the issue yourself, please post it as an answer. It will be helpful to someone else.